# QGIS slope layer help

Tags: qgis, slope

I have a DEM that was made from UAV/photogrammetry techniques by Maps Made easy.
In QGIS I loaded the DEM and then made a slope raster layer.
My values go from 0 to a huge number like 23456e+07. Does that seem right?
The highest slope on the terrain is not much more than 28%.
I think the layer is spitting out wrong data. Do I need to enter a Z factor?
Also, when I enter my formula in raster calculator `("slope@1" > 28) * 0 + ("slope@1" < 28) * 1` it turns my whole image black.

My end goal is to display a map with the georeferenced jpeg with areas over 28% slope shaded in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula indicates that boolean values are treated like False = 0 and True = 1 in Raster calculator, so your conditions return either 0 or 1. By means of that your formula is wrong, because

`("slope@1" > 28) * 0` is allways 0 (since `n * 0 = 0`)

`("slope@1" < 28) * 1` is either 0 or 1.

I think your formula should be

`("slope@1" < 28) * "slope@1"` returning `slope@1` if `"slope@1" < 28` and `0` otherwise.

**UPDATE**

In order to restrict the maxiumum value to `28` you might use

`("slope@1" < 28) * "slope@1" + ("slope@1" >= 28) * 28`

... with the 2nd summand returning `28` for values above `28`.

Furthermore I suggest investigation of your DEM data in points, where the slope has unexpected high values.

Comment: Your suggested formula worked better than mine.

Comment: Also I find that when I create the slope layer and I use a scale factor, I get better numbers for my min/max. When I don't use conversion factor I get weird numbers like black -1743, white-3.46759e+07. Should I keep using the scale factor 111120?

Comment: I think I wouldn't use a scale factor, but you might use the raster calculator to restric your result to max=28, see update in my answer.

Comment: Ok. The DEM is from a newly logged area with slopes. The DEM picked up some standing trees along the edges of area of interest. I wonder if that is messing up the slope raster when it's generated. I wonder if I should clip the DEM raster first, cutting out the unwanted tall trees